# .ics file for all day events - dropping off one day

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm writing a simple holiday request app for our department. It's writes an .ICS file which it then emails to all the necessary people.

An example of the contents of this is:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Holiday
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20141216T111644Z
UID:20141216T111644Z@random.com
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150223T000100
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150225T000100
SUMMARY:mcvpjd3-Holiday
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR'
```

I've also tried the start and end dates to just have the dates with the T000100 removed or with a T000000. I've tried a start date with T000100 and tagged the end date with T235959

When importing into a google calendar it works fine for single day events, but for the multi day event above, it puts it as a 2 day event instead of a 3 day event.

Is it me doing something wrong or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your file is not correct as an online validator would indicated: you have twice `BEGIN:VCALENDAR`, you also specify the `DTSTART` as a `DATE` but have a `DATETIME` value.

below is a corrected version

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Holiday
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/London
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20141216T111644Z
UID:20141216T111644Z@random.com
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150223
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150225
SUMMARY:mcvpjd3-Holiday
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Sorry, original post probably wasn't clear.
I have used just dates without the times, this is where I started and where I get the problems.
Also the first 6 lines were a duplication when creating the post and not in the original .ICS file - Sorry - didn't notice when posting.